Deserialize a List of object by it's className in c#
I have a class which dynamically deserializes a string by it's className. I have the following code:
Type objValueType = ByName(this.className);
object deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json,objValueType);

ByName-Method:
private Type ByName(string name) {
return
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .Reverse()
        .Select(assembly => assembly.GetType(name))
        .FirstOrDefault(t => t != null)
    ??
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .Reverse()
        .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes())
        .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name.Contains(name));
}

This works fine if my json-string has only one object. But now I want to deserialize a List of this objects by classname and the json-string is an array of these object.
How do I solve this problem?
thx
©a-x-i

"I have a class which dynamically deserializes a string by it's className" - and this is how the next Log4J vulnerability was created...

Allowing arbitrary types to be constructed and deserialized by class name using Json.NET is already know to introduce severe security vulnerabilities including vulnerability to injection of arbitrary code.  See External json vulnerable because of Json.Net TypeNameHandling auto? and TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json.  So, don't do this.

Anyway, use typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(objValueType ) as shown in this answer by Andrew Hare to C# instantiate generic List from reflected Type.
